# understand sklearn QuantileTransformer

Tags: python, math, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I try to use QuantileTransformer to transform several columns, but the results don't seem to be convenient. Moreover, it depends on the column order even for a small dataset.

I understand that there is a way to create an individual transformer for each feature, but as I read [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.QuantileTransformer.html), this function should accept (n_samples, n_features) object.

Here is [google colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1fHk5ap3r931SSXBe7a16mZJlAKGuYKhx) to reproduce the results.

Is there a way to apply QuantileTransformer and get consistent results (so that same original values are mapped to same transformed values instead of one to many)?

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import QuantileTransformer

def unique_values(x):
    return x.unique().tolist()

df = pd.read_csv('https://storage.googleapis.com/ml_universities/california_housing_train.csv', usecols=[0, 1])
columns = ['latitude', 'longitude']

qt = QuantileTransformer()
q_features = qt.fit_transform(df)
suffix = '__qt'
qdf = df.join(pd.DataFrame(q_features, columns=columns), rsuffix=suffix)

for col in columns:
    q_col = f'{col}{suffix}'
    print({col: qdf[col].nunique(), q_col: qdf[q_col].nunique()})
    gdf = qdf.groupby(col)[q_col].agg([pd.Series.nunique, unique_values])
    print(gdf.sort_values('nunique', ascending=False).head())
```

Results:

```
{'latitude': 840, 'latitude__qt': 827}
          nunique                                      unique_values
latitude                                                            
34.07       102.0  [0.9865865865865866, 0.9719719719719734, 0.963...
34.08       101.0  [0.980980980980981, 0.9474474474474475, 0.9214...
34.06        94.0  [0.9846403596403596, 0.932932932932933, 0.9294...
34.10        88.0  [0.9891329870516945, 0.9882813721745806, 0.987...
34.05        87.0  [0.9719719719719734, 0.9269269269269284, 0.923...
{'longitude': 827, 'longitude__qt': 842}
           nunique                                      unique_values
longitude                                                            
-118.31       50.0  [0.6276276276276276, 0.5721203907954981, 0.511...
-118.32       49.0  [0.5369214480068981, 0.504004004004004, 0.4804...
-118.12       49.0  [0.5418393378488674, 0.5415415415415415, 0.540...
-117.25       48.0  [0.5335335335335335, 0.5327261051927988, 0.452...
-118.15       47.0  [0.5495495495495496, 0.5418393378488674, 0.541...
```

Different column order:

```
df = pd.read_csv('https://storage.googleapis.com/ml_universities/california_housing_train.csv', usecols=[0, 1])
columns = ['longitude', 'latitude']

qt = QuantileTransformer()
q_features = qt.fit_transform(df)
suffix = '__qt'
qdf = df.join(pd.DataFrame(q_features, columns=columns), rsuffix=suffix)

for col in columns:
    q_col = f'{col}{suffix}'
    print({col: qdf[col].nunique(), q_col: qdf[q_col].nunique()})
    gdf = qdf.groupby(col)[q_col].agg([pd.Series.nunique, unique_values])
    print(gdf.sort_values('nunique', ascending=False).head())
```

Results:

```
{'longitude': 827, 'longitude__qt': 827}
           nunique            unique_values
longitude                                  
-124.35        1.0  [9.999999977795539e-08]
-118.31        1.0     [0.5900900900900901]
-118.41        1.0      [0.531031031031031]
-118.40        1.0     [0.5355355355355356]
-118.39        1.0      [0.542542542542544]
{'latitude': 840, 'latitude__qt': 842}
          nunique                             unique_values
latitude                                                   
37.74         2.0  [0.7602602602602603, 0.7577577577577578]
37.37         2.0  [0.6806806806806807, 0.6816816816816816]
32.54         1.0                   [9.999999977795539e-08]
38.34         1.0                      [0.8848848848848849]
38.36         1.0                      [0.8873873873873874]
```

Comment: Could you be more specific about how the results are "not convenient"? What were you hoping for?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you didn't change the order of the columns, but simply renamed the columns. If you do it this way, then you will get the correct results. I am also supplying a `random_state` parameter for good measure.

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import QuantileTransformer

def unique_values(x):
    return x.unique().tolist()

df = pd.read_csv('https://storage.googleapis.com/ml_universities/california_housing_train.csv', usecols=[0, 1])
columns = ['latitude', 'longitude']
# Change the column order
df = df[columns]

qt = QuantileTransformer(random_state = 0)
q_features = qt.fit_transform(df)
suffix = '__qt'
qdf = df.join(pd.DataFrame(q_features, columns=columns), rsuffix=suffix)

for col in columns:
    q_col = f'{col}{suffix}'
    print({col: qdf[col].nunique(), q_col: qdf[q_col].nunique()})
    gdf = qdf.groupby(col)[q_col].agg([pd.Series.nunique, unique_values])
    print(gdf.sort_values('nunique', ascending=False).head())
```

produces same output, just in a different order (which is what you desired because the column order was switched), as

```
df = pd.read_csv('https://storage.googleapis.com/ml_universities/california_housing_train.csv', usecols=[0, 1])
columns = ['longitude', 'latitude']
df = df[columns] # Changing the column order

qt = QuantileTransformer()
q_features = qt.fit_transform(df)
suffix = '__qt'
qdf = df.join(pd.DataFrame(q_features, columns=columns), rsuffix=suffix)

for col in columns:
    q_col = f'{col}{suffix}'
    print({col: qdf[col].nunique(), q_col: qdf[q_col].nunique()})
    gdf = qdf.groupby(col)[q_col].agg([pd.Series.nunique, unique_values])
    print(gdf.sort_values('nunique', ascending=False).head())
```